# How can I add some html text to the highchart while exporting it to PNG, PDF,Jpeg?

Tags: highcharts, export

I have used these options.

```
 exporting: {
    enabled: false,
    allowHtml:true
}
```

This is my export function.

```
export(type: any) {
     this.graph.exportChart({ type: type });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only on export (add title) then use

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/473g44vz/2/)

```
 exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        events: {
          load: function() {
            var dynamic = document.getElementById('dynamic').value
            this.setTitle({
              text: dynamic
            });
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        align: 'right',
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: This worked. But i want to add text to the right corner of the exported image.

Comment: do you want random text only on export or it will always show in chart at right corner

Comment: How can i add chartoptions while exporting? Because i want to add text dynamically.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/473g44vz/2/ use this , i added input text to add text dynamically

Comment: This worked.
this.graph.exportChart({type: type},{
        title:
        {
          text: isNullOrUndefined(this.source)?'':this.source,
          align: 'right'
        }
      });

Comment: add fiddle link